# ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support for C++ and Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode11

I have a pure Objective-C Xcode project for my iOS application. Is there any reason why I receive the following error message by mail after submitting my App to AppConnect? I don't have any Swift dependencies in my project.

> ITMS-90426: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is
>   missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of
>   Xcode and resubmit it.

I use the latest `Xcode 11.0` version from the App Store. I made a full rebuild. I don't use CocoaPods, I can't even find the String "Swift" in my entire project

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36546996/299924)?

Answer (score 1):

well this is a common issue when an application is builded by a beta version or Xcode installed directly from a file not from AppStore, this error appears on frameworks, libs, bundles or build is not related directly with Swift.

To fix the issue you need to download Xcode from AppStore and update the latest public version with Mojave or Catalina (4th October 2019). Remember clean and rebuild, check the other linker flags to not include Swift flags or build phases dependencies.

I hope it helps you, cheers :D

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I used the latest Xcode 11 from the App Store and I get the error message above

Comment: I have two projects with pure Objective-C and C++ and I fixed it with my answer, but maybe your issue is related with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559204/invalid-swift-support-the-swiftsupport-folder-is-empty/36546996#36546996