# Invalid Swift Support when submitting App

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11

A while back I was trying to submit an App using `Xcode version 11.1 (11A1027)` but I received an email from Apple with the following message:

> ITMS-90424: Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is empty. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.

From what I know, `11A1027` is already a released version and so I am not very sure why there is a need to use the GM version of Xcode. Does anyone have any idea?

I tried some of the methods suggested in other posts but somehow could not resolve it.

Is this a bug in Xcode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Swift Support / The SwiftSupport folder is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32559204/invalid-swift-support-the-swiftsupport-folder-is-empty)

Comment: @KirilS. Not a duplicate as the link that you mentioned is more for Objective C based program

Comment: how you are creating iPA file? if you are making iPa file somehow using script then this issue happen.

Comment: I encountered this issue when i created build using script and fixed by adding swift support folder when it make final iPA file.

Comment: I did the archive using xcode itself, not using command line.  Could not figure out how to resolve this and so reverted back to xcode 10.3.  In xcode 11.1, Application loader has also been removed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728413/invalid-swift-support-the-swiftsupport-folder-is-empty/59833694#59833694

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728413/invalid-swift-support-the-swiftsupport-folder-is-empty/59833694#59833694

Answer (score 3):

Solved for me in June 2020.

MacOS Catalina 10.15.5

Xcode Version 11.5 (11E608c)

Check that **Command line tools**(Xcode->Preferences->Locations) have this value

Configure **PROJECT** in project settings

1. Click to you project in Xcode.
2. Select project name
3. Set filter to **Basic** and **Levels**
4. Find **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** field (if not found - play with filters)
5. Set **YES** to this field for PROJECT(debug and release)

Configure **TAGET** in target settings

1. Click to you project in Xcode.
2. Select target name
3. Set filter to **Basic** and **Levels**
4. Find **Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** field (if not found - play with filters)
5. Set **YES** to this field for **PROJECT**(debug and release) and set **NO** to this field for **TARGET**(debug and release)
   [see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cek9x.png)

Clean project and create archive(Product->Archive)

In the dialog window right click to the created archive name -> Show in Finder

Right click to the archive name in Finder -> Show Package Contents

**Delete SwiftSupport** folder here

After that upload your build using AppStore Connect in Xcode with default settings.

Answer (score 2):

I received this same email after uploading an `.ipa` file to App Store Connect through the **Transporter** app. The following is where I went wrong: **I distributed the app using ad hoc.**

The following steps are the solution for my error:

1. Archive app
2. Distribute on TestFlight and the App Store
3. Export
4. Open `ExportOptions.plist` in the newly created folder from the export.
5. Make sure the `method` property has the value `app-store` if you are uploading to App Store Connect/TestFlight like me.
6. Drag and drop the exported `.ipa` file to **Transporter**.
7. Deliver your app to upload it.

And that's it!

Original answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62568526/10374366

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think it’s a bug. But the best thing you can do is to just reinstall Xcode from the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was in this ["Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing" with Xcode 7.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981628/invalid-swift-support-the-swiftsupport-folder-is-missing-with-xcode-7-3-1). We needed to use the new -exportOptionsPlist flag with xcodebuild instead of the older -exportFormat and -exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity flags. The plist just needs to have the method key set to app-store.

Comment: In xcode 11.1, Application loader has been removed, if the ipa is created with xcodebuild, how will the ipa be uploaded to the app store connect?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to swift 5.0 and going to workspace settings, build system and set it to New Build System. This solved it for me in a React Native project using native iOS views. As far as I know swift 5 makes doesn't use the swift support folder any more.